# How to post webform with file to webmethod using Jquery/Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webforms

Is this even possible? I have a webform with certain textboxes etc and a file upload element. I am trying to send the data to webmethod using `.ajax()` method. 
It seems to me that it is not possible to send file content to the webmethod in this manner. I am not even able to hit the webmethod.

```
script type="text/javascript">
    var btn;
    var span;
    $(document).ready(function (e) {

        $('#btnsave').on('click', function (event) {

            Submit();
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    })

    function Submit() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "SupplierMst.aspx/RegisterSupplier",
            data: "{'file' : " + btoa(document.getElementById("myFile").value) + ",'biddername':" + document.getElementById("txtsuppliername").value + "}",
            async: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data, status) {
                console.log("CallWM");
                alert(data.d);
            },
            failure: function (data) {
                alert(data.d);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert(data.d);
            }
        });

    }
    </script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<input id="txtsuppliername" type="text" /><br />
<input type="file" id="myFile">
```

**Code behind :**

```
[WebMethod]
public static string RegisterSupplier(string file, string biddername)
{
  // break point not hit

  return "a";
}
```

I have been trying to find solution to this for hours now. Nobody seems to be able help me out on this. Is this even possible using this approch. If not how do I do it? Somebody suggested that I should try to submit entire form instead of passing individual values.

Comment: try using Json stringify to send data to the service

Comment: @dazzlingkumar Jsonstringify to send file?

Comment: yes send it in Json format to service then it will hit the service

Comment: @Arbaaz you want to send file name in webmthod ?

Comment: @MairajAhmad I want to send file itself.

Comment: File cannot be posted like this via ajax.

Comment: @MairajAhmad then what do I do? I have been googling , asking people on stackoverflow for hours now. Most of them seems to think that it can be done, although I didnt think its possible. Should I go back to using server  controls?

Comment: There is a jquery plugin which you can use. Jquery file upload.

Comment: @MairajAhmad yes but I also have other fields like textboxes and dropdowns which i need to save along the file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77786/discussion-between-mairaj-ahmad-and-arbaaz).

Comment: Apart from some other possible issues, you are missing single quotes in here: `{'file' : " + btoa(document.getElementById("myFile").value) + ",`. It should be something like this: `{'file' : '" + btoa(document.getElementById("myFile").value) + "',` because the result of `btoa()` is a string (and same thing happens for `biddername`). But that should raise an error in the console. Are you seeing any errors?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro I am not seeing any errors, but thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Are you targeting any browser in particular?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro if it works on chrome an mozilla that would be  enough

Comment: @Arbaaz, did the answer help you?

Answer (score 4):

This can be done without any library, by using the [JavaScript FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader). With it, [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=filereader) can read the content of the file using JavaScript once it has been selected by the user, and then you could proceed as you were doing (encoding it as a string, and sending it over to the server).

The code would be like this (using the one above as a reference):

```js
// NEW CODE
// set up the FileReader and the variable that will hold the file's content
var reader = new FileReader();
var fileContent = "";

// when the file is passed to the FileReader, store its content in a variable
reader.onload = function(e) {
  fileContent = reader.result;
  
  // for testing purposes, show content of the file on console
  console.log("The file content is: " + fileContent);
}

// Read the content of the file each time that the user selects one
document.getElementById("myFile").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  var selectedFile = document.getElementById('myFile').files[0];
  reader.readAsText(selectedFile);
})
// END NEW CODE

var btn;
var span;

$(document).ready(function (e) {
  $('#btnsave').on('click', function (event) {
    Submit();
    event.preventDefault();
  });
})

function Submit() {

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "SupplierMst.aspx/RegisterSupplier",
    // changed this line too!
    data: {
              'file': btoa(fileContent), 
              'biddername': document.getElementById("txtsuppliername").value 
          },
    async: true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data, status) {
      console.log("CallWM");
      alert(data.d);
    },
    failure: function (data) {
      alert(data.d);
    },
    error: function (data) {
      alert(data.d);
    }
  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txtsuppliername" type="text" /><br />
<input type="file" id="myFile">
```

You can run the code above, select a file (use a plain text file for testing so it's readable), and check the console to see its content. Then the rest of the code would be the same (I made a slight change to fix the parameters in the AJAX call).

Notice that sending the file like this has limits: if you use the GET method, you'll have a shorter parameter size limit, and with POST it will depend on the server settings... but I guess that you had those limits even for a file.

Comment: Sorry for replying late. I am getting `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null`

Comment: Where are you getting that error? Could you share your code?

Comment: HERE: `document.getElementById("myFile").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  var selectedFile = document.getElementById('myFile').files[0];
  reader.readAsText(selectedFile);
})`

Comment: What is the id of the `input type="file"`?

Comment: And where have you placed that code within your page?

Answer (score 0):

First of all go to App_Start>>RouteConfig.cs>>settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off; and then Just Replace your function by my code it will definitely work for you,
Good Luck..

```
function Submit() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "UploadImage.aspx/RegisterSupplier",
        data: "{'file' : " + JSON.stringify(document.getElementById("myFile").value) + ",'biddername':" + JSON.stringify(document.getElementById("txtsuppliername").value) + "}",
        async: true,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data, status) {
            console.log("CallWM");
            alert(data.d);
        },
        failure: function (data) {
            alert(data.d);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert(data.d);
        }
    });
```