# Pass file to webmethod using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to send an image to a webmethod.  The user first selects an image and then hits a submit button.  I'm using

```
<input type=file id="btnUpload" />
```

I then put the file from the input control into an array

```
// declare outside of event
var files = {}
// inside btnUpload change event
files.push({ content: file, fileName: file.name });
```

and my object I'm passing to the webmethod is

```
public class PostedFiles {
    public HttpPostedFile PostedFile { get; set; }
    public int inspectorId { get; set; }
    public int inspectionId { get; set; }
}
```

the signature of the webmethod is

```
[WebMethod]
public static string UploadFile(PostedFiles postedFiles)
```

jquery code

```
$('#btnUpload).click(function () {
    var data = {
        PostedFiles: files[0].content
        inspectorId: 5,
        inspectionId: 7
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../Default.aspx/UploadFile",
        data: JSON.stringify({ postedFiles: data }),
        dataType: "text",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.status === "error") {
                alert('Successful Error!!');
            }
            else {
                alert('Did it!!');
            }
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert('FAILED');
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert('ERROR');
        }
    });
});
```

I'm only sending one image in this example, but my goal is to send an array of images - or HttpPostedFile[] - but since filereader works async, I don't know how to make a single ajax call while processing multiple filereader async calls.

If I comment out all the file part, the webmethod is called property.  I've checked the data before the ajax call and it's populated with the file.  I've found articles saying to use FileReader to convert the file before uploading, but I can't figure out how to do that because FileReader works asynchronously (I don't want to do the convert until the btnUpload event is fired). I did manage to use reader.ReadAsArrayBuffer and did get it into the files[] array, but could not figure out what should the type be on the PostedFile.content property.  I've tried string, string[], and byte[].

Does anyone know how to pass an image file (or any other) to a WebMethod via an ajax call?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to post webform with file to webmethod using Jquery/Ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233472/how-to-post-webform-with-file-to-webmethod-using-jquery-ajax)

Comment: Just realized HttpPostedFile probably isn't the right type.  Tried object and object[] with no luck.  Tried File and File[], but get errors about using static types.