# Sending file from JQuery Ajax to C# Webmethod

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I want to send data from aspx page to .cs Webmethod using jQuery Ajax. my html code is as shown below

```
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="txtName">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <form action="" id="AttachmentForm1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <input type="file" name="UploadFile1" id="txtUploadFile1" class="btn btn-sm" />
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

And my javascript code as below

```
 function saveData() {

    var file = $("#txtUploadFile1")[0].files[0];

    $.ajax({
        url: 'CCA_Form.aspx/SaveData',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify({  Name: txtName, fileData: file }),
        success: function () {
            alert("Data Added Successfully");
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Error while inserting data");
        }
    });}
```

And my c# code as below

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static bool SaveData(string Name, string[] fileData)
    {
        //Breakpoint
        return true;
    }
```

how can i get uploaded file in Webmethod in c#?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to post webform with file to webmethod using Jquery/Ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233472/how-to-post-webform-with-file-to-webmethod-using-jquery-ajax)

Comment: You are missing a bracket here :`data: JSON.stringify( Name: txtName, fileData: file })` in order to send a json string from javascript object.

Answer (score -1):

You need to do using `XMLHttpRequest`
This guys has a really nice tutorial about it. see it if it helps you: [Click Here](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/uploading-files-ajax)

Or

For your above code:

```
var filename = $("#txtUploadFile1").val();
 $.ajax({
    url: 'CCA_Form.aspx/SaveData',
    type: 'POST',
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    data: {file: filename},
    success: function () {
        alert("Data Added Successfully");
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("Error while inserting data");
    }
});}
```